# SP2010 Attach Event Receiver to specific list programmatically - runs for all lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010, eventreceiver

I'm attaching a event receiver to a single list (Web scope). But the ER runs for all lists in the Web. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014020/how-can-i-add-event-receiver-only-for-list-with-specyfic-template-id) says that the feature, the ER is deployed in, have to be Web scope. This is the case.

The Feature is activated programmatically bound to an ER of a list in the TLS.

```
newProjectWeb.Features.Add(new Guid("57e21870-6285-4e0a-b9a0-067f774492ae"));
```

Please see my code below. Am I missing an Update or anything?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
public void AddEventReceiverToMemberList()
    {
        try
        {
            _clsLists.AddEventReceiverToList(Web, ProjectMemberList.LIST_INTERNAL_NAME, typeof(SCMUProjectMemberList), SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded);
            _clsLists.AddEventReceiverToList(Web, ProjectMemberList.LIST_INTERNAL_NAME, typeof(SCMUProjectMemberList), SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting);
            _clsLists.AddEventReceiverToList(Web, ProjectMemberList.LIST_INTERNAL_NAME, typeof(SCMUProjectMemberList), SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdated);

            Web.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

public void AddEventReceiverToList(SPWeb web, string listName, Type eventReceiverClass, SPEventReceiverType eventType)
    {
        SPList list = this.GetListByName(web, listName);            

        string className = eventReceiverClass.FullName;
        string assemblyName = Assembly.GetAssembly(eventReceiverClass).FullName;

        list.EventReceivers.Add(eventType, assemblyName, className);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the event receiver for a single list..

Refer [Here](http://seminda.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/creating-sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Check the end of the post, Changing the attribute to "ListTemplateId" to "ListURL" in Elements.xml

Answer (score 0):

In the Elements.xml file replace:

`<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">`
by

`<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Your List Name">`